# Can't get rid of TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, string, object, callable

I'm trying to make/train a twitter sentiment analyser in ipython notebook and am having serious problems with one section of code:

```
import csv

#Read the tweets one by one and process it
inpTweets = csv.reader(open('SampleTweets.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',',    quotechar='|')
tweets = []
 for row in inpTweets:
    sentiment = row[0]
    tweet = row[1]
    processedTweet = processTweet(tweet)
    featureVector = getFeatureVector(processedTweet, stopwords)
    tweets.append((featureVector, sentiment));
#end loop
```

And I'm getting this error:

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-bbcb1b9f05f4> in <module>()
      7     sentiment = row[0]
      8     tweet = row[1]
----> 9     processedTweet = processTweet(tweet)
     10     featureVector = getFeatureVector(processedTweet, stopwords)
     11     tweets.append((featureVector, sentiment));

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

And help would be seriously great, thanks!

Comment: `processTweet` is undefined in the code you've shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your processedTweet should be a `str` hence you can't call it.

Example -

```
>>> a = 'apple'
>>> a(0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#212>", line 1, in <module>
    a(0)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

But when I use index, it's fine. Callable means you are using that as a function like sum etc.

```
>>> a[0]
'a'
```

Comment: Thank you! And sorry for being an idiot...but what should I do?

Comment: I am not aware of your api, you need to check your `processedTweet`, it should have an error or you need to use it in a different way.

Comment: It looks like it needs to process your tweets, so you should have that as function somewhere. But again, no idea how that is implemented. Hope that helps.

Comment: @RachelDbbs, you can upvote and accept the answer if that helped. thx.